# timer in message application

Tags: java, android

HELLO Developers,
                     I have taken over a project in android environment which i am completely new to, which imbibes a timer facility so that user can time his sms to be sent. Which messaging API will prove to be a help in this. Hoping to get good response from your side.

Comment: We are not Android developers, but rather Android users.  This question may be migrated to StackOverflow, which is for developers.  You will need to edit your question to be more specific, and in fact I recommend using [http://developer.android.com/index.html](http://developer.android.com/index.html) to learn more so that you can ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a messaging API. SMS sending is included in the Android SDK. To delay the sending I would recommend to use a Timer and schedule it with an delay:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask, long)